# Why won't this CSS work?

Tags: css, css-selectors

I have a document looking something like:

```
...  
<div class="myClassA">  
 ...  
 <span class="myClassB">  
 ...  
 </span>  
 ...  
</div>
```

I'd like to be as specific as possible in my CSS. But this doesn't work:

```
div.myClassA span.myClassB  
{  
...  
}
```

Although, this does work:

```
div span.myClassB  
{  
...  
}
```

Why can't I specify the class on the div as I did in the first example?

Comment: Is it a HTML document? This notation looks unfamiliar...

Comment: Please see http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help to learn how to format code.

Comment: Pedro - you can click on the `{}` button to format code and display real HTML and CSS, you don't have to use `[these]`.

Comment: The first CSS selector should work. Why do you think it does not work?

Comment: The only possibility I can think of is that you're accidentally closing your `div` prematurely. Could we see the complete HTML please?

Comment: if the second one works, then I suppose you have a typo in your real class name

Comment: CSS is sometimes case sensitive (DOCTYPE is XHTML in some browsers). Maybe there is a slight difference there?

Comment: Have you tried using Firebug to see exactly what css attributes are being applied to your rendered html?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It works: http://jsfiddle.net/XKeBg/

Comment: @Pedro: Which is why I asked you to paste your full HTML code.

Answer (score -1):

Change

```
div.myClassA span.myClassB
```

To

```
div.myClassA, span.myClassB
```

You just forgot the comma.

Comment: No---I only want to format the span when it is a descendant of the div

Comment: Ah, sorry, I have a cold today and tried to read it before it was formatted

Comment: No, I don't think he did; `span.myClassB` *seems* to be a child of `div.myClassA`.

Comment: No, the comma will select **both** the `div` and the `span`.  The OP probably wants to **only** select the `span` (which is inside the `div`)

Comment: Just FYI, I didn't down-vote you. You gave it a shot. Simple mistake.